# Merging two lists into a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog, append, concatenation

I have two lists:

```
X = [a,b,c]
Y = [d,e,f]
```

I want the outcome to be:

```
Z = [[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]
```

However, when I use append I get:

```
 Z=[a,b,c,d,e,f].
```

Any suggestions on how I should do this?

Answer (score 3):

You may just create a list with both lists:

```
add_lists(X, Y, [X, Y]).
```

then `add_lists([a,b,c], [d,e,f], Z)` would yield `Z = [[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]`.

You can also just inline this, `Z=[X, Y]`

Answer (score 1):

gusbro's answer is what you should do using plain unification, but just commenting on what you said:

> when I use append:

You can use append differently, and get the answer you want:

```
?- X=[a,b,c],
   Y=[d,e,f],
   append([X], [Y], Z).

X = [a, b, c],
Y = [d, e, f],
Z = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]].
```